# Vue: text field with typeahead

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I want to make a text field with typeahead. I have a list of words and when you start typing them, a suggestion appears with the word(s). The thing is, it needs to be able to do it multiple times, every new word you type, it can show you a suggestion.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Not what I want though, it only shows 1 suggestion. Every word I type, it needs to have suggestions for that word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vue-suggestion](https://github.com/iamstevendao/vue-suggestion) to accomplish this easily. Take a look at the [demo](https://iamstevendao.github.io/vue-suggestion/) to see if this suites you.

This is my implementation of App.vue which differs slightly.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ items }}
    <vue-suggestion :items="results"
                    v-model="item"
                    :setLabel="setLabel"
                    :itemTemplate="itemTemplate"
                    @changed="inputChange"
                    @selected="itemSelected">
    </vue-suggestion>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import itemTemplate from './item-template.vue';
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        item: {},
        items: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Golden Retriever'},
          { id: 2, name: 'Flying Squirrel'},
          { id: 3, name: 'Cat'},
          { id: 4, name: 'Catfish'},
          { id: 5, name: 'Squirrel'},
        ],
        itemTemplate,
        results: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      itemSelected (item) {
        this.item = item;
      },
      setLabel (item) {
        return item.name;
      },
      inputChange (text) {
        // your search method
        this.results = this.items.filter(item => item.name.includes(text));
        // now `items` will be showed in the suggestion list
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```